# App crashes on adding data in a hook very fast

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, hook, react-functional-component

```
const [count,setCounter] = useState(0)


const increaseCounter = () =>{
setCounter(value=>value+1)
}

<Button onPress={()=>increaseCounter()}/>
```

i am running above code and display counter in the app. But it crashes my app. As i am doing it very fast. Not able to get why is this happening. Please tell me how to hold it for some milliseconds so that i will work in async manner.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [react docks example](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Example() {
  // Declare a new state variable, which we'll call "count"
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const [count,setCounter] = useState(0)
        
const increaseCounter = () => {
setCounter(count + 1);
}
        
<Button onPress={()=>increaseCounter()}/>
```